# 2D array into if statement without loop - Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have defined a function which includes an if statement. I then want to pass in the X array in the function, which is a 2D array. I tried using np.all, but although it gives no error, it sets ALL the X values to "if abs(x) < L:". How would I be able to pass a 2D array (X) into the function properly?

```
x = np.arange(-10.,15.+1.,1.)
y = np.arange(-4.,4.+0.1,0.1)
eps = 0.1
L = 2.
k = np.pi/(2.*L)

def q2(x):
    if abs(x) < L:
        return (((-3.*eps*np.cos(k*x))+(k*(np.sin(k*x)-np.exp(3.*eps*(x-L)))))/((9.*eps**2.) + k**2.))
    if x > L:
        return 0.
    if x < -L:
        return (-k*(1.+np.exp2(-6.*eps*L))*np.exp(3.*eps*(x+L)))/((9.*eps**2.) + k**2.)

def u2(x,y):
    return 0.5*q2(x)*(y**2. - 3.)*np.exp(-0.25*y**2.)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
vel_x=u2(X,Y)
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but from your code right now, it looks like `x` is a 1-D array?

Comment: I don't get it. Currently you call `np.all(x)` which is either `True` or `False`. If you take that as a number (as you do when calling `abs` and `>`/`<`), it's either `1` or `0`, so `abs` is not necessary. If you rather wanted `np.all(abs(x))` or `np.all(x>L)`, none of the 3 cases in `q2` is ever reached with your choice of `x` and `y` and `None` is returned. What do you actually want?

Comment: @Windmill at the end of the code, X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y), vel_x = u2(X,Y)

Comment: @Michael np.all(x) was a failed attempt at getting the 2D array X (big X) into the function through the if statement. When I call vel_x = u2(X,Y), the big X which is a 2D array will go through the u2(x,y) function that calls the q2(x,y) function. In the q2(x,y) function, there is an if-statement, which does not take the 2D array X. What I am looking for is how to get the values of X through the if statement.

Comment: @Michael So maybe put more clearly, I'd like it to do this: 
vel_x = u2(X,Y) >>>> Put X, Y through u2(x,y) function which includes q2(x) function. Now when X is being passed into the q2(x) function, I want every value of the 2D-array X to go through it. I'll change my code here to not confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where(CONDITION)` to get an array of indices, which can be used to access only those parts of `x` you are currently interested in:

```
def q2(x):

    q = np.zeros(x.shape)

    # for abs(x) < L
    ind = np.where(np.abs(x) < L)
    q[ind] = (((-3.*eps*np.cos(k*x[ind]))+(k*(np.sin(k*x[ind])-np.exp(3.*eps*(x[ind]-L)))))/((9.*eps**2.) + k**2.))

    # for x < -L
    ind = np.where(x < -L)
    q[ind] = (-k*(1.+np.exp2(-6.*eps*L))*np.exp(3.*eps*(x[ind]+L)))/((9.*eps**2.) + k**2.)

    return q
```